# Xna SpriteBatch Matrix.Decompose()

Tags: xna, 2d

What I am looking to do is to be able to push and pop transform matrices into SpriteBatch. I have 2 sprites, parent and child, and the child should be scaled, rotated, translated relative to the parent.

I currently have an implementation using textured quads but I think this should be possible using the built in SpriteBatch class and using Matrix.Decompose(). I'm not sure how to pass the decomposed values to SpriteBatch once I've decomposed them though.

I understand how to keep the matrix stack, I'm just looking for an example of using values coming from Matrix.Decompose() in conjunction with SpriteBatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this one out myself finally. Most of the credit belongs to this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/brandf/archive/2010/02/18/using-retained-sprites-zoomengine-graphics-and-zoomengine-animation-part-3.aspx) though.

You can use this method to decompose your matrix:

```
private void DecomposeMatrix(ref Matrix matrix, out Vector2 position, out float rotation, out Vector2 scale)
{
    Vector3 position3, scale3;
    Quaternion rotationQ;

    matrix.Decompose(out scale3, out rotationQ, out position3);

    Vector2 direction = Vector2.Transform(Vector2.UnitX, rotationQ);
    rotation = (float)Math.Atan2((double)(direction.Y), (double)(direction.X));
    position = new Vector2(position3.X, position3.Y);
    scale = new Vector2(scale3.X, scale3.Y);
}
```

You can then build a transform matrix your leaf sprites like so:

```
Matrix transform = 
    Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(this.Scale, 1.0f)) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(this.Rotation) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(this.Position, 0));
```

For your parent sprites, include the origin:

```
Matrix transform = 
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-this.Origin, 0)) *
    Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(this.Scale, 1.0f)) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(this.Rotation) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(this.position, 0));
```

Multiply by all the matrices in the stack in reverse order.

Comment: I've been looking all over for how to go from a transform matrix's quaternion to a float that a SpriteBatch can use and this is absolutely it. For anyone coming to this, you will notice that matrix.Decompose(...) returns a bool. I don't suggest putting it in an if statement. It appeared to return false no matter what for me, but still outputs the correct values for scale, rotation, and position.